# Get spatialReference Domain, with XY Precision

Tags: arcobjects, coordinate-system, c#

I'm trying to get a spatialReference domain from `prj` file by using the [function](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000001t000000) :

```
private void ConstructCoordinateSystem(bool highPrecision)
{
    // SpatialReferenceEnvironment is a singleton object and needs to use the Activator class.
    Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriGeometry.SpatialReferenceEnvironment");
    System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    ISpatialReferenceFactory3 spatialReferenceFactory = obj as
        ISpatialReferenceFactory3;

    // Create a geographic coordinate system from a .prj file that contains the well-known string.
    // You might need to update the file location.
    ISpatialReference3 spatialReference =
        spatialReferenceFactory.CreateESRISpatialReferenceFromPRJFile(
        "C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.0\\Coordinate Systems\\Geographic Coordinate Systems\\World\\WGS 1984.prj")as ISpatialReference3;

    // Determines whether you are constructing a high- or low-precision spatial reference.
    IControlPrecision2 controlPrecision = spatialReference as IControlPrecision2;
    controlPrecision.IsHighPrecision = highPrecision;

    ISpatialReferenceResolution spatialReferenceResolution = spatialReference as
        ISpatialReferenceResolution;
    ISpatialReferenceTolerance spatialReferenceTolerance = spatialReference as
        ISpatialReferenceTolerance;

    // The following three methods are key: construct horizon, then set the default x,y resolution and tolerance.
    spatialReferenceResolution.ConstructFromHorizon();
    spatialReferenceResolution.SetDefaultXYResolution();
    spatialReferenceTolerance.SetDefaultXYTolerance();

    // Check the x,y spatial domain.
    double xMin;
    double xMax;
    double yMin;
    double yMax;
    spatialReference.GetDomain(out xMin, out xMax, out yMin, out yMax);

    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Domain : "+ xMin +", "+  xMax + ", "+ yMin +", "+ yMax);
}
```

When I use a `prj` file other than WGS, it works perfectly.

But when I use a WGS file, in this case I need to add a test `hasXYPrecision` before calling `spatialReference.GetDomain()`.

The problem is that the property `hasXYPrecision` returns always false, in both cases (WGS file and non-WGS file)

Any ideas?